# Deferred function doesn't work as expected in IE with jQuery 1.12

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have 2 functions where I am trying to run one function and then the other.  I have implemented this line in my code:

```
function1().done(function2);
```

In function1 at the end I have placed this code:

```
return $.Deferred().resolve();
```

This functionality works in both Firefox and Chrome, but does not seem to be working in Internet Explorer 11.  I get no errors, but the functions are not running one after the other like it should be.  Does anyone know why this is happening or know of a workaround/other way to do this that would work in all browsers?

I have been playing around with this example using Internet Explorer and experiencing the issue I mention above with it (the alert shows up before the text gets hidden, should happen the other way around):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function1 = function() {
    $("p").hide("slow");
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
  }

  function2 = function() {
    alert("Text hidden now.");
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      function1().done(function2);
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Hide</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have also tried implementing a callback in function1 but that also does not seem to work for me in Internet Explorer (does work in Firefox and Chrome, however)

Comment: For the record in FF, Chrome & IE10 I get the alert before the text is hidden too. Looks like this is not just a simple IE issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hide` is one of many animations which returns immediately but completes out of process. It has a second parameter, a callback function, which is executed when the animation completes. You should be `resolve`ing the deferred from that callback:

```
function1 = function() {
   var def = $.Deferred();
   $("p").hide("slow",function(){def.resolve(); });
   return def.promise();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/64dy3tL3/1/

Above left for posterity, even though it does not answer the question.

---

You should not be returning `$.Deferred().resolve()` - that makes no sense. You need to return `promise()` from the `$.Deferred()` and `resolve()` it separately.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean by that.  However, I was trying to just use that as an example - my actual application are two functions not using animations where I just would like to run one function and once that first function finishes, run the second function.

Comment: @EvanL - Then you've asked the wrong question. By trying to simplify the issue you've obfuscated the real issue. See update. It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Shouldn't you do `return def.promise();`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - Yes, yes I should have.

Comment: Thanks this has helped tremendously.  Sorry for asking the wrong question.